# How to force render of property panel?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

How can I force the SharePoint Framework to re-render the property panel of my Client Side Web Part?

In detail I would like to execute the `getPropertyPaneConfiguration()` method once again when the user performs a certain action which needs to update the rendered controls in the property panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `refresh()` method of the Property Pane which you can access through the web part's `context` property:

```
this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
```

Comment: Make sure to put it inside you async part...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and Waldek's answer didn't work twice for me, but this did:

```
this.context.propertyPane.close();
this.context.propertyPane.open();
```

Don't worry, there will be no visual feedback of the re-opening of the panel.